# Cakephp With MongoDB: Unable to set a new variable in the beforeSave function

Tags: php, mongodb, cakephp, cakephp-model

How can I set a variable to a collection before saving data to MongoDB i.e in `beforeSave()` method

Lets Say i have controller

```
class BooksController extends AppController
{
    $model_name = 'Books';

    function save() {
        if($this->request->is('post')) {
        $data = $this->request->data['forms'];
        $this->$model_name->save($data);  // Already loaded the model
        }
    }
}
```

And Model

```
class Books extends AppModel 
{

    function beforeSave($options = array()) {
        $this->data['Books']['active'] = '1'; 
        // Tried this as well but found unstructured (key,value) pair `$this->data['active'] = '1';`
        //print_r($this->data) found correct format but active field is not getting saved in MongoDB
        return true;
    }

}
```

Please let me know any further clarification is required.
Any help really been appreciated!

Comment: I am usign [this library](https://github.com/ichikaway/mongoDB-Datasource)